# How do I visualize points in Paraview 5.4.1?

Tags: points, paraview

To whom it may concern,

I write a Fortran program to track particles.  It creates the following output in .vtk format for Paraview:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="16" NumberOfCells="0">
      <Points>
        <DataArray type="Float64" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii">
           -3.743016E-0003  5.787635E-0002 -1.104483E-0010
           -3.244210E-0003  5.700748E-0002  5.074001E-0011
           -2.747819E-0003  5.623541E-0002  9.991296E-0011
           -2.246957E-0003  5.556635E-0002 -5.163316E-0011
           -1.749140E-0003  5.501747E-0002  1.470107E-0010
           -1.248574E-0003  5.460318E-0002 -1.527216E-0011
           -7.487991E-0004  5.432458E-0002 -9.874857E-0012
           -2.504589E-0004  5.418813E-0002  8.798235E-0012
            2.504575E-0004  5.418813E-0002 -2.789069E-0011
            7.487986E-0004  5.432458E-0002  1.118293E-0011
            1.248530E-0003  5.460317E-0002 -1.385613E-0011
            1.749141E-0003  5.501748E-0002  1.227365E-0011
            2.246955E-0003  5.556635E-0002 -4.099211E-0011
            2.747817E-0003  5.623541E-0002  8.857913E-0012
            3.244206E-0003  5.700748E-0002  1.460764E-0010
            3.743038E-0003  5.787647E-0002  3.815671E-0011
        </DataArray>
      </Points>
      <Cells>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="ascii">
        </DataArray>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="ascii">
        </DataArray>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="types" format="ascii">
        </DataArray>
      </Cells>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

Sixteen points are defined in the file, with their coordinates, no cells, and no point data too.  When I read this file with Paraview (I use version 5.4.1) I just don't see the points.  I tried the 3D Glyph and then Sphere, but that doesn't help.

Is something missing in the file I create?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the "Point Gaussian" representation.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, but where do you find this option?  In my Paraview I only see:
- 3D Glypghs
- Outline
- Points
- Surface
- Surface With Edges
- Volume
- Wireframe

Comment: Use ParaView 5.11 instead of ParaView 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

What you do is correct, but you are facing a problem of camera. All you need to do is use the "Reset" or the "Zoom To Data" button in the toolbar [image: buttons icons].

I hope it helps.